# Batch executing query in RPostgres returning same data

Tags: r, rpostgresql, wrds-compusat, dbconnect, rpostgres

I am currently trying to download a large database using RPostgres - however, when I try to write the results to csvs in batches, it writes the same data over and over (always the first 1M records). Here is the code I am currently using:

```
wrds <- dbConnect(Postgres(),
                  host='wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu',
                  port=9737,
                  dbname='wrds',
                  sslmode='require',
                  user='username')

res <- dbSendQuery(wrds, "SELECT VARNAMES FROM DATABASE WHERE CONDITIONS")
i = 0

while (!dbHasCompleted(res)) {
  i <- i+1
  chunk <- dbFetch(res, 1000000) # Fetch 1,000,000 at a time
  filename <- paste("path\\EuropeanSMEs_", i)
  write.csv(data, filename, row.names = FALSE)
}

dbClearResult(res)
dbDisconnect(wrds)
```

How do I amend the code that it fetches a new set of 1M rows on every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this. Using `PROC EXPORT` from SAS would work (you would then need to download the `.csv` file from WRDS). If I really needed to have a CSV file of a large WRDS data set, I might adapt my function [here](https://github.com/iangow/wrds2pg/blob/bb6faa45227160d0fe169f14a048e310ae149521/wrds2pg/wrds2pg.py#L451) to write to a local CSV file rather than a PostgreSQL database.

Another option might be to look for a variable that roughly partitions the data into one million rows. For example, `year` or similar and use the `WHERE` part of the SQL to get rows in chunks. Using `dbplyr` (see examples [here](http://iangow.me/far_2021/fin-state.html), you could probably write a small function to `collect()` data by year or some other partitioning variable and write to a CSV.